# Shift pandas dataframe column values based on date time range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a timeseries data as below

| time | values |
| --- | --- |
| 8/7/2023 00:00 | 41.55 |
| 8/7/2023 00:15 | 90.33 |
| 8/7/2023 00:30 | 10.00 |
| 8/7/2023 00:45 | 11.55 |
| 8/7/2023 01:00 | 23.33 |
| 8/7/2023 01:15 | 24.00 |

Now i want to shift the values column in between date time `flat_start = 00:00` to `flat_end = 00:30` forward in rows by filling NaN values for the shifted time range. And the values which will come as extra after shift should be automatically removed as below.

| time | values |
| --- | --- |
| 8/7/2023 00:00 | NaN |
| 8/7/2023 00:15 | NaN |
| 8/7/2023 00:30 | NaN |
| 8/7/2023 00:45 | 41.55 |
| 8/7/2023 01:00 | 90.33 |
| 8/7/2023 01:15 | 10.00 |

I used df.shift(periods=3) method to shift 3 values.I wonder whether there's a better solution based on date time range?

Comment: Can you explain more `flat_start = 00:00` ? In data is possible first datetime not start by `00:00` ?

Comment: It is possible in data first datetime not start by 00:00

Comment: Ok, so what happens with data before `00:00` ?

Comment: It can be from previous date 23:45

Comment: I add solution for filtering data between `flat_start` and `flat_end` with shift by `45Min`, can you test?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df = df.set_index('time')

df = df.shift(freq='45Min').reindex(df.index)
print (df)
                     values
time                       
2023-08-07 00:00:00     NaN
2023-08-07 00:15:00     NaN
2023-08-07 00:30:00     NaN
2023-08-07 00:45:00   41.55
2023-08-07 01:00:00   90.33
2023-08-07 01:15:00   10.00
```

---

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df = df.set_index('time')

flat_start = '00:00'
flat_end = '00:30'

df = df.between_time(flat_start, flat_end).rename(lambda x: x + pd.to_timedelta('0:45:00')).reindex(df.index)
print (df)
                     values
time                       
2023-08-07 00:00:00     NaN
2023-08-07 00:15:00     NaN
2023-08-07 00:30:00     NaN
2023-08-07 00:45:00   41.55
2023-08-07 01:00:00   90.33
2023-08-07 01:15:00   10.00
```